# QThread: Making parallel execution with GUI-Feedback blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

## Scenario

Lets say, I have a procedure called `parallelRun`. It would take a list of workers, each having a `getWorkAmount():int`, a `run()` method, a `finished()` signal and a `cancel()` slot:

```
void parallelRun( std::vector< Worker* > workers );
```

Its implementation should:

### 1. Open a `QPogressDialog`:

```
unsigned int totalWorkAmount = 0;
for( auto it = workers.begin(); it != workers.end(); ++it )
{
    totalWorkAmount += ( **it ).getWorkAmount();
}

LoadUI ui( 0, totalWorkAmount, this );
```

with

```
class LoadUI : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    LoadUI( int min, int max, QWidget* modalParent )
        : totalProgres( 0 )
        , progressDlg( "Working", "Abort", min, max, modalParent )
    {
        connect( &progressDlg, SIGNAL( canceled() ), this, SLOT( cancel() ) );

        progressDlg.setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
        progressDlg.show();
    }

    bool wasCanceled() const
    {
        return progressDlg.wasCanceled();
    }

public slots:

    void progress( int amount )
    {
        totalProgres += amount;

        progressDlg.setValue( totalProgres );
        progressDlg.update();

        QApplication::processEvents();
    }

signals:

    void canceled();

private slots:

    void cancel()
    {
        emit canceled();
    }

private:

    int totalProgres;
    QProgressDialog progressDlg;
}
```

### 2. Create one thread for each worker

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< QThread > > threads;
for( auto it = workers.begin(); it != workers.end(); ++it )
{
    std::unique_ptr< QThread > thread( new QThread() );

    Worker* const worker = *it;
    worker->moveToThread( thread.get() );

    QObject::connect( worker, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread.get(), SLOT( quit() ) );
    QObject::connect( &ui, SIGNAL( canceled() ), worker, SLOT( cancel() ) );
    QObject::connect( *it, SIGNAL( progressed( int ) ), &ui, SLOT( progress( int ) ) );

    thread->start( priority );

    threads.push_back( std::move( thread ) );
}
```

### 3. Run them simultaneously

```
for( auto it = workers.begin(); it != workers.end(); ++it )
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod( *it, "run", Qt::QueuedConnection );
}
```

`load()` is run when the user clicks an UI-button.

## Problem

How am I supposed to extend this code, if I want to make `parallelRun` block until all workers are finished, without freezing the `QProgressDialog`?

### Deliberations

#### Using a barrier

I tried adding the following code at the end of the `parallelRun` routine:

```
QApplication::processEvents();
for( auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it )
{
    ( **it ).wait();
}
```

The impact of this few lines of extra-code is, that `LoadUI::progress` is *never entered*, since the GUI-thread is *asleep* and therefore it's event loop isn't processed: In Qt, signals are delivered to slots by posting them to the event loop of the thread, associated to the object the slot belongs to. This is why the `progressed` signal of a worker is never delivered.

I think, the appropriate solution would be to run `QApplication::processEvents()` *within the GUI-thread* anytime a `progressed` signal is emitted by a worker. On the other hand, I guess this cannot be done, since the GUI-thread is asleep.

#### Another possible solution

Another possibility would be to use an *active waiting*-like solution:

```
for( auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it )
{
    while( ( **it ).isRunning() )
    {
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
for( auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it )
{
    ( **it ).wait();
}
```

This also requires adding the following line of code right after `thread->start( priority );`:

```
while( !thread->isRunning() );
```

I don't think that this is a nice solution, but at least it works. How can this be done without the drawbacks of active waiting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the threads' `finished()` signals to wait for them all to finish in the main GUI loop instead of using `QApplication::processEvents`. The progress dialog modality will ensure that only that dialog window is active until it is explicitly closed.

```
class WorkerManager : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    // to be able to access the threads and ui, they are defined as a members
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<QThread> > threads;
    LoadUI *ui;

    int finishedThreadCount;
public:
    WorkerManager() 
        : finishedThreadCount(0)
    {
        // Open the QProgressDialog
        ...
        // Create and start the threads
        ...
        // Connect the finished() signal of each thread 
        // to the slot onThreadFinished
        for( auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it )  {
            QObject::connect(
                it->get(), SIGNAL(finished()), 
                this, SLOT(onThreadFinished()) );
        }
    }

private slots:
    void onThreadFinished() {
         ++finishedThreadCount;

         if(finishedThreadCount == threads.size()) 
         {
              // clean up the threads if necessary
              // close the dialog
              // and eventually destroy the object this itself
         }
    }
};
```

Or you can run a nested `QEventLoop` to wait for the threads to finish synchronously while still keeping the GUI responsive:

```
// Open the QProgressDialog
...
// Create and start the threads
...
// Create and run a local event loop,
// which will be interrupted each time a thread finishes
QEventLoop loop;
for( auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it )  
{
    QObject::connect(
        it->get(), SIGNAL(finished()), 
        &loop, SLOT(quit()) );
}  
for(int i = 0, threadCount = threads.size(); i < threadCount; ++i) 
    loop.exec();
```

If the progress reach the maximum only when the work is completely done, you can use `progressDlg->exec()` instead of a `QEventLoop` which will block until the maximum is reached or until the user clicks on the "Cancel" button.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how this is supposed to help me. How would I use this within a routine (that shall block for the duration of the operation) without the `QProgressBar` being frozen?

Comment: You do not block your GUI (i.e. the main thread). The user cannot use the GUI because the modal progress bar dialog is in front and superposes the rest of your GUI. Therefore the main thread is still running and can update the progress bar until the finished() signal closes it.

Comment: That's right, but it is my *goal* to make my `parallelRun` routine blocking. Think of a `QFileDialog` for example. If you call its `getOpenFileName` method from the UI thread, the code execution **blocks**, until the user has either chosen a file to open or aborted the dialog. Therefore, it is a blocking method, **nevertheless**, the UI is not frozen, the user can interact with the dialog. What I need is a similar behavior, only that I have to accomplish some computational tasks (and present their current progress to the user) instead of presenting a file selection dialog.

Comment: @theV0ID I edited the answer. But blocking with a nested event loop like that might cause some problems (See ["Unpredictable exec()"](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/02/23/unpredictable-exec/)(qt labs) or ["Nested Event Loops"](http://delta.affinix.com/2006/10/23/nested-eventloops/)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building your own. Maybe QThreadPool is what you are looking for?

QThreadPool has a function for waiting for all workers.

Comment: How is this meant to solve my problem?

Can you please give an example?

Comment: @theV0ID It wouldn't solve anything, the waiting functions are blocking, so it would be the same as your own "barrier" solution.